# Bitcoind JSON-RPC - getbalance with 0 confirmations not included

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc

When I access bitcoind through JSON-RPC and query:

> getbalance '*' 0

It does not include transactions with 0 confirmations.

Only when a transaction has least 1 confirmation it is included in that rpc call.

Bitcoin-Qt correctly shows the number I want to get in Overview > Wallet > Unconfirmed

I am using Bitcoin 0.8.6 beta